# docker run vs create+start: why are created containers different?

Tags: docker

Related to

- [docker container started in Detached mode stopped after process execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087099/docker-container-started-in-detached-mode-stopped-after-process-execution/35206183#35206183)
- [The right way to keep docker container started when it used for periodic tasks](https://serverfault.com/questions/661909/the-right-way-to-keep-docker-container-started-when-it-used-for-periodic-tasks)

I do understand the difference between docker `run` and `create` + `start`, but don't understand how the actual containers created in these two ways differ.

Say I create and run a container with

```
docker run -dit debian:testing-slim
```

and then stop it. The created container can later be started with

```
docker start silly_docker_name
```

and it'll run in the background, because the entry command for the image is bash.

But when a container is first created

```
docker create --name silly_name debian:testing-slim
```

and then started with

```
docker start silly_name
```

then it'll exit immediately. Why isn't bash started, or how come it exits in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference for a container process that is a shell (like `bash` in your debian example) is that a shell started without a terminal+interactive "mode" exits without doing anything.

You can test this by changing the command of a `create`'d container to something that doesn't require a terminal:

`$ docker create --name thedate debian date`

Now if I run `thedate` container, each time I run it it outputs the date (in the logs) and exits. `docker logs thedate` will show this; one entry for each run.

To be explicit, your `docker run` command has flags `-dit`: *d*etached, *i*nteractive (connect STDIN), and *t*ty are all enabled.

If you want a similar approach with create & start, then you need to allocate a `tty` for the created container:

`$ docker create -it --name ashell debian`

Now if I start it, I ask to attach/interactively to it and I get the same behavior as run:

`$ docker start -ai ashell
root@6e44e2ae8817:/#`

**NOTE:** **[25 Jan 2018]** *Edited to add the `-i` flag on `create` as a commenter noted that as originally written this did not work, as the container metadata did not have stdin connected at the create stage*

Comment: Thanks man. Wasn't aware that `-t` flag was available for `create` as well.

Comment: -1; this just plain doesn't work for me. If I do `docker create -t --name ashell debian` and then `docker start -ai ashell`, I do indeed see `root@6e44e2ae8817:/#` but the shell is hung; it won't accept input or show any further output. If I replace the `docker create` command with `docker run -dit --name ashell debian`, on the other hand, everything works perfectly. The mystery of why these commands are different remains, for me, unsolved.

Comment: My mistake in translating commands into the answer; the `-i` flag is still required on the `create` step so that **stdin** is connected on the start, given it exists in the created metadata for the container. I have edited the answer to show this correctly now.

Comment: @PhilE are you sure you need `-ai` on `start`? when i do `docker start -i container` I get the same result as `docker start -ai container`. Or what is difference?